# How to turn Nested JSON into Pandas Data Frame using Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am new in understanding the JSON format and how to properly traverse it. I wanted to ask how I can read in a JSON file with nested keys and turn it into a Pandas Data Frame. (Example data below)

I tried using json_load from the JSON package of Python and read_json from Pandas except they do not arrange the nested keys (below json_sample.txt) into their own. The tutorials on JSON I came across were relatively simple and do not apply to my case.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

"json_sample.txt"

```
{"Top_Shelf": [{"packageName": "big_game1",
  "sku": "big_game1_product1",
  "status": "active",
  "purchaseType": "User_A",
  "defPrice": {"price": "6", "currency": "CAD"},
  "prices": {"DZ": {"price": "6", "currency": "DZD"},
   "AU": {"price": "7", "currency": "AUD"},
  "listings": {"en-US": {"title": "game_currency_1",
    "description": "Pack2"}},
  "defaultLanguage": "English"}},
 {"packageName": "big_game1",
  "sku": "big_game1_bundle1",
  "status": "active",
  "purchaseType": "User_B",
  "defPrice": {"price": "1", "currency": "CAD"},
  "prices": {"DZ": {"price": "1", "currency": "DZD"},
   "AU": {"price": "1", "currency": "AUD"},
  "listings": {"en-US": {"title": "bundle",
    "description": "Pack1"}},
  "defaultLanguage": "English"}}]}
```

Final Structure of the results I would like to get (But even a table with all of the keys as their own column would be great

```
packageName     sku             countryCode   currency  price

big_game1   big_game1_product1  CA          CAD      6

big_game1   big_game1_product1  DZ          DZD      6

.   .   .   .   .

.   .   .   .   .

.   .   .   .   .

big_game1   big_game1_bundle1   AU          AUD      1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that'll do it (:

```
import json
import pandas as pd


json_str = '''
{"Top_Shelf": [{"packageName": "big_game1",
  "sku": "big_game1_product1",
  "status": "active",
  "purchaseType": "User_A",
  "defPrice": {"price": "6", "currency": "CAD"},
  "prices": {"DZ": {"price": "6", "currency": "DZD"},
   "AU": {"price": "7", "currency": "AUD"},
  "listings": {"en-US": {"title": "game_currency_1",
    "description": "Pack2"}},
  "defaultLanguage": "English"}},
 {"packageName": "big_game1",
  "sku": "big_game1_bundle1",
  "status": "active",
  "purchaseType": "User_B",
  "defPrice": {"price": "1", "currency": "CAD"},
  "prices": {"DZ": {"price": "1", "currency": "DZD"},
   "AU": {"price": "1", "currency": "AUD"},
  "listings": {"en-US": {"title": "bundle",
    "description": "Pack1"}},
  "defaultLanguage": "English"}}]}
'''

json_dict = json.loads(json_str)
shelf = json_dict['Top_Shelf']
df_shelf = pd.DataFrame(pckg for pckg in shelf)
```

Comment: Hi, a_json should be json_dict. This gives me some clear-up but how could I tease apart the ```prices``` key further? I dont mind it all being individual rows. 

What does ```(pckg for pckg in shelf)``` do?

Comment: Yeah, my bad about the a_json. and as for the (pckg for pckg in shelf) it takes every "package" or object in the array of the "Top_Shelf" and inserts it into our DataFrame object.